# Generics: how to enforce restrictions between keys and values in a Map

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

The problem: I've a Function Object interface defined in a class:

```
    public static interface FunctionObject<T>  {
        void process(T object);
    }
```

I need it generic because I'd like to use T methods in the process implementations.
Then, in other generic class, I've a Map where I have classes as keys and function objects as values:

```
    Map<Class<T>, FunctionObject<T>> map;
```

But I also want the map to accept subtype classes and function objects of supertypes OF THE KEY TYPE, so I did this:

```
    Map<Class<? extends T>, FunctionObject<? super T>> map; //not what I need
```

The basic idea is to be able to use the map as follows:

```
    //if T were Number, this should be legal
    map.put(Class<Integer>, new FunctionObject<Integer>(){...});
    map.put(Class<Float>, new FunctionObject<Number>(){...});
    map.put(Class<Double>, new FunctionObject<Object>(){...});
```

As I want to enforce the FunctionObject has the type of the class key or a supertype, what I really would like to define is this:

```
    Map<Class<E extends T>, FunctionObject<? super E>>> map;
```

How can I achieve the desired effect? Is a typesafe heterogenous container the only option? What would the Map generic types look like to allow populating it from a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parametrized container, seems to work just fine:

```
public class MyMap<T>
{
    interface FunctionObject<X> {}

    private Map<Class<? extends T>, FunctionObject<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <E extends T> void put(Class<E> c, FunctionObject<? super E> f)
    {
        map.put(c, (FunctionObject<Object>) f);
    }

    public <E extends T> FunctionObject<Object> get(Class<E> c)
    {
        return map.get(c);
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        MyMap<Number> map = new MyMap<>();

        map.put(Integer.class, new FunctionObject<Integer>() {});
        map.put(Float.class, new FunctionObject<Number>() {});
        map.put(Double.class, new FunctionObject<Object>() {});
    }
}
```

**Edited** to comply to the question. Sadly there is no way to avoid the downcasting to object.

**Edit** added `get()`.

Comment: Yes, but implementing the get is when the fun starts XD.

Comment: The `get()` can only ever return `FunctionObject<Object>()`: since the parameter is a *superclass* of T and the key, there is no way to establish an upper bound. I added it to the answer.

Comment: I think it is a reasonable concession to make.

Comment: There is really no alternative: unless you specify an upper bound, there is no way for Java to know which superclass of the key type the value had, so it must default to Object. You can manually upcast it in the specific place if you can make a valid assumption on the type (but then, why use generics?).

Comment: but `FunctionObject<Integer>` is not a subtype of `FunctionObject<Object>`, so it is not logically correct for it to return `FunctionObject<Object>`, because that indicates to the caller that it's safe to pass anything to this function object, which is false. Also, if we had reified generics, this would crash

Comment: "`FunctionObject<Integer>` is not a subtype of `FunctionObject<Object>`" hence the cast in `put()`; "because that indicates to the caller that it's safe to pass anything to this function object" since `FunctionObject<>` is generic without restriction (that the OP told us about) it must be able to accept any class argument.

Comment: @user102008 There's a cast in the `put` method so only `FunctionObject<Object>` are stored.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with encapsulation, assuming you only use the map through the method which check this on a per entry basis.

The following add method avoids the need to double up on the type as well.

```
public class Main {
interface FunctionObject<T> { }

private final Map<Class, FunctionObject> map = new LinkedHashMap<Class, FunctionObject>();

public <T> void add(FunctionObject<T> functionObject) {
    Class<T> tClass = null;
    for (Type iType : functionObject.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()) {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) iType;
        if (!pt.getRawType().equals(FunctionObject.class)) continue;
        Type t = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        tClass = (Class<T>) t;
        break;
    }
    map.put(tClass, functionObject);
}

public <T> void put(Class<T> tClass, FunctionObject<T> functionObject) {
    map.put(tClass, functionObject);
}

public <T> FunctionObject<T> get(Class<T> tClass) {
    return map.get(tClass);
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.add(new FunctionObject<Integer>() {
    });
    FunctionObject<Integer> foi = m.get(Integer.class);
    System.out.println(foi.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]);
}
}
```

prints

```
Main.Main$FunctionObject<java.lang.Integer>
```

You can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` if you want to disable the warning.

The point is; there is no way to describe the constraint you have in the field declaration, you can achieve the same result if you use accessor methods which do the check on a per entry basis.  You can add runtime checks as well if you need to ensure raw types are correct.

Comment: But this only allows type T and nothing more, isn't it? And by the way, that Map declaration gives a warning for using raw types.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of Peter's answer: it's not the map that guarantees the type safety. It's the fact that the only way to put/get values in/from the map is to use these methods, which always associate a Funtion<T> with a Class<T>. Of course, if you use raw types when calling these methods, you don't have any guarantee.

Comment: Ok, so there's no choice but to code a typesafe container. I wonder if this is the same in C#.

Comment: Can't you make an encapsulating parametric class then? To avoid warnings and inconsistencies.

Comment: @Viruzzo which type would you make it?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I added it as an answer.

Comment: I still can't see where it checks that the Class key is `Class<? extends T>` and the value is `FunctionObject<? super (class type)>`, which was my main question And there are 6 warnings, seems a lot to me. Before patching so many warnings, I'd redesign it without generics.

Comment: You can add SupressWarning at the start of the class.  The warnings make sense because you are trying to do something which the compiler doesn't directly support so it can't check what you are doing is entirely safe.

Comment: He's right though in that it makes little sense to use generics (that are only used to check at compile time) if you are going to throw it around with a lot of unchecked casts anyway.

Comment: @Viruzzo Unless all the unchecked casts are enclosed in your container.  Many of the Java Collections have unchecked warnings, but they are hidden away in the implementation.  The caller doesn't need to know about them.